# Problems with large number of static pages in website

Tags: performance, seo, webserver, static-pages

We have 2 million businesses in our database. My client wants to create 1 static page for each business so that the pages are indexed by Google. He wants each page to have the following URL structure:-

`http://website/business-name/category/city/zip/`

So an example page could have the URL:-

`http://example.com/pizza-hut/restaurant/newyork/12345/`

What I want to know is the disadvantages of making this much static pages and any advantages they have? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A clear disadvantage is that this makes a lot of files to manage, for you, the server, the cache system, the file system and the source control system.

And that's totally useless as you can can let the rest of the world, including Google bots, think there are different pages without making different pages, using [htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) rules : they allow [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine).

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between a static and generated web page to Google.  It will crawl the page if there is a link to it.  If there is no link to a static page it has no way of finding it.  So there is no advantage of a static page unless it is faster to read from disk then to generate on the fly.